# Historic land satellite imagery service

Tags: satellite

I need to examine certain areas over a period of several years to view the effects of urbanisation. It's largely a visual exercise. I've found one tool that does this and is easy to use[1] but it only provides the historic images for the most zoomed-out levels.

Can anyone recommend a resource to achieve this? We have no budget, but I'm open to paid services if no free ones are available.

PS: If there is specific terminology I should be aware of to help with internet searches, please let me know. The important thing is the record of historical images to compare land changes over time such as deforestation. The location of interest this time is Australia.

1: https://zoom.earth/#-33.340544,146.887772,8z,sat,am,2015-05-06

Comment: It might be better to post this question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can try USGS's [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). It's free, contains several datasets, and covers the world.